# Only Last TensorFlow Probability Layer Being Output (Multiple Times)

Tags: tensorflow, for-loop, keras, tensorflow-probability

I'm building a TensorFlow Probability Bayesian network.  In the example below, I've got a simple 2 distribution output, but both outputs are coming from the last distribution added to the network (ignoring any prior distributions added).  Here's a concrete code example that shows what I'm talking about.

Import some packages, and some helper code

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers, Model
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
ZERO_BUFFER = 1e-5 

dist_lookup = {
    'normal': {
        'dist': tfp.distributions.Normal,
        'count': 2,
        'inputs': {
            'loc': False,
            'scale': True,
        }
    },
    'exponential': {
        'dist': tfp.distributions.Exponential,
        'count': 1,
        'inputs': {
            'rate': True,
        }
    }
}
```

Now let's create some fake data to use.

```py
n = 100000
np.random.seed(123)
x1 = np.ones(shape=(n, 1))
x2 = 2 * np.ones(shape=(n, 1))
x3 = 3 * np.ones(shape=(n, 1))
X = pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate([x1, x2, x3], axis=1), columns=['x1', 'x2', 'x3']).astype(int)
```

Now let's build a toy model that demonstrates what I'm talking about.  Notice that I'm trying to build the distribution layers with a `for` loop.  If I manually build each distribution layer by typing it out, I don't get the weird behavior below.  It only happens when I define it in a `for` loop, BUT I need to build a larger model with a dynamic number of distributions so I need to be able to build it using a loop of some kind.

```py
def create_dist_lambda_kwargs(prior_input_count: int, input_dict: dict, t):
    kwargs = dict()
    for j, (param, use_softplus) in enumerate(input_dict.items()):
        x = prior_input_count + j
        if use_softplus:
            kwargs[param] = ZERO_BUFFER + tf.nn.softplus(t[..., prior_input_count + j])
        else:
            kwargs[param] = t[..., prior_input_count + j]
    return kwargs


input_layer = layers.Input(X.shape[1])
# distributions = ['exponential', 'normal']
distributions = ['normal', 'exponential']
dists = list()
reshapes = list()
total = 0
for i in range(len(distributions)):
    param_count = dist_lookup[distributions[i]]['count']
    dist_class = dist_lookup[distributions[i]]['dist']
    dists.append(
        tfp.layers.DistributionLambda(
            lambda t: dist_class(
                **create_dist_lambda_kwargs(
                    prior_input_count=total,
                    input_dict=dist_lookup[distributions[i]]['inputs'],
                    t=t,
                )
            )
        )(input_layer)
    )
    reshapes.append(layers.Reshape((1,))(dists[i])    )
    total += param_count
total = 0

output = layers.Concatenate()(reshapes)
model = Model(input_layer, output)
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam', metrics=['mae', 'mse'])
```

Oddly, if I remove the `total = 0` line after the `for` loop above, the code above crashes.  I'm assuming that's somehow related to the other issue below.

Now, if I make predictions with the input data (remember all of the rows of the input data are the same), then I should get a large sample from both of the output distributions that we can plot.

```py
pred = model.predict(X)

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)
fig.set_size_inches(10, 5)
for i, ax in enumerate((ax1, ax2)):
    ax.hist(pred[:, i], bins=50)
    ax.set_xlabel(f'Output{i + 1} Value')
    ax.set_title(f'Output{i + 1} Histogram')
```

If the `'exponential'` value is the last in the `distributions` list, then the plot looks something like the image below; both outputs looks like an exponential distribution
[image]

If the `'normal'` value is the last in the `distributions` list, then the plot looks something like the image below; both outputs look like a normal distribution
[image]

So, my question is WHY is the model build getting confused by the `for` loop and treating both outputs like the last distribution created in the `for` loop, and how can the code be fixed to make it work as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't read the whole question, but you're definitely hitting [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295290/what-do-lambda-function-closures-capture) when you create the lambda in the loop.

Comment: That link blew my mind!  I had no idea that was a known issue when defining lambda functions in loops!

Comment: Yeah haha. It gets everyone eventually! Now you know. Pass it on! ☺️